# How can I register a class member as callback function to a queue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, c++17, metaprogramming

The **minimal example code** is the following :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>

// Queue from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721421
template<typename T>
class Queue {
   public:
      void Push ( T x ) { theQueue.push( x ); for (auto c : theCallBacks) { c(*this); } }
      T Pop() { auto data = T{theQueue.front()}; theQueue.pop(); return data; }
      void Register( std::function<void(Queue<T>&)> ql ) { theCallBacks.push_back( ql ); }
  private:
      std::queue <T> theQueue;
      std::vector<std::function<void(Queue<T>&)>> theCallBacks;

};

void cinFct(Queue<std::string> recvQ, Queue<std::string> sendQ) {
    auto input = std::string{};
    while(true) { std::cin >> input; sendQ.Push(input); }
}

class ConsoleModule {
        Queue<std::string> sendQ; Queue<std::string> recvQ;
        std::thread cinThread; // Simulates execution on external hardware
    public:
        void recvData(Queue<std::string>& q) {
            auto recvd = q.Pop(); std::cout << "RECEIVED FROM THREAD : " << recvd << std::endl;
            // do stuff with recvd
        }
        void sendData(Queue<std::string>& q, std::string s)  { q.Push(s); }
        ConsoleModule() :sendQ{}, recvQ{}, cinThread{cinFct, sendQ, recvQ} {
            recvQ.Register(std::bind(&ConsoleModule::recvData, *this, std::placeholders::_1));
        }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     auto testModule = ConsoleModule{};
}
```

In this code, I declare a **queue with callbacks** for which I would like to register a **class member function**. The `ConsoleModule` simulates the exchange of information with external hardware through those queues. I have a very long template error at compilation (line of `recvQ.Register(...)`) that can be viewed [at this link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5d073832f6a2741).

What is going on ?

Comment: I think the error is only here: `std::bind(&ConsoleModule::recvData, *this, std::placeholders::_1)`. Changing it to the correctly `std::bind(&ConsoleModule::recvData, this, std::placeholders::_1)` removes the compile error. Can you recheck with that fix?

Comment: Indeed, that fixes the main error. I still have that weird error `static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues`, though

Comment: Well, is not one problem that main exits while the thread is still running, destroying ConsoleModule and its thread? I guess you want to wait until it is finished. I don't get your assertion error in compile explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/7LlBsq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with this:

```
ConsoleModule() :sendQ{}, recvQ{}  {

    recvQ.Register([this](Queue<std::string>& q) {
        recvData(q);
    });

    std::thread t([this]() {
        cinFct(recvQ, sendQ);
    });

    cinThread = std::move(t);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works ! I still have that weird error `static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues, though`

Comment: You can even remove the `this->` from the second line and/or replace the `Queue<`...`>&` with `auto&`.  Minmally `recvQ.Register([=](auto &q) { recvData(q); });`

Comment: I've updated the answer to help with the compile issue you are having through the std::thread initialization.